Can't jump/swing Spider-Man Miles Morales
Earlier today the jump and swing abilities just randomly stopped working. I don't know why.
I'd just gotten the suit for the Davis brother's beat.
Reinstalling the game didn’t fix the problem.
Can anyone help me fix it?
I'm playing on PS5

Have you tried restarting the game or console? Or reinstall the game?

I'll try reinstalling the game

yeah that didnt fix it

What were you doing in the game before it stopped working?

I had just gotten the suit for the davis brothers beat

What platform is this? Restart the controller? https://www.reddit.com/r/SpidermanMilesMorales/comments/jxablb/bug_cant_jumpswingwallrun/

Try restarting from the last checkpoint, as per Malady’s link.

Did you try restarting from the latest checkpoint or resetting your controller?
